# Referencing a view's ID in class (how to us R.id.name in class)

Tags: java, android

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to reference a view's ID in a custom class.  The goal is to create a class that can change the text inside a button and change the visibility of a textView from gone to visible. The code works fine as a stand alone, but I'd like to not repeat it a bunch of times for all the drop down sections being created.

In the code below, when initiating in my main class, nothing happens when this is attached to an onclick listener

How do I reference what would otherwise be R.id.btn1 and R.id.text1 so I can use this as a class?

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class toggleSection {
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private boolean isOpen = false;

    public toggleSection(Button button, TextView textView) {
        this.button = button;
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    public void toggleSection(Button button, TextView textView, String title) {
        if (!isOpen) {
            button.setText(title + " ►");
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isOpen = true;
        } else {
            button.setText(title + " ▼");
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Turns out I didn't declare the variable type in the method below. This is why you don't code when you're tired. Edited question

Answer (score 0):

In your `toggleSection()`, you are providing references to your `button` and `textview` again and using *those* references only. However, you should be using instance variables here that you must have initialized in the constructor.